# RedirectResponse not working

Tags: redirection, 8

I'm in the process of porting my modules from D7 to D8. No real problems so far, but...

I have a multistep form from where I need to redirect to /node/add/xyz in the last step. (All required input form data is stored in D8 TempStore before the redirect).
In d7 I used the simple and functional drupal_goto('node/add/xyz') function which is gone in D8 for whatever reason.

I looked into core modules to see how it is done in the D8 way and it seems RedirectResponse() from the Symfony routing system is the way to go. However doing something like this:

```
return new RedirectResponse(url('node/add/xyz', array('absolute' => TRUE)));
```

But this is silently ignored, no error, nothing. I read that doing RedirectResponse from somewhere in the code may not work. So my next idea of doing it was to use a form redirect in this way:

```
$form_state['redirect_route'] = array(
  'route_name' => 'node.add',
  'route_parameters' => array(
    'node_type' => 'xyz',
  ),
);
```

even without any effect. I'm out of ideas and wish drupal_goto() back. Hopefully someone out there can help me out!

Thanks in advance
bzrudi

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Where exactly are you placing the `return` code?

Comment: @Mołot No way to know if this is a bug until we know where the code is being used. I haven't seen a problem with Symfony's `RedirectResponse` yet in Drupal 8 so this is likely to be a bug in the OP's code.

Comment: @Clive The redirect is within the submitForm() method of my form.

Comment: Does [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AredirectForm/8) answer your question?

Comment: @Clive yes! I had an unneeded $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; within the last form step ;-) I searched hours within the D8 API and missed that one. However you helped me within minutes with my first DrupalAnswers question. Perfect - thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: No problem :) I'm going to summarise this into answer so hopefully it'll help others with the same problem

Comment: @Clive OK, close vote retracted.

Comment: @Clive, could you please add the answer so we can accept it and close this question? I really want to keep [8] clean of unanswered questions, see :)

Comment: @chx I'm on it...just need some clarification on Berdir's comment to my original answer. Cheers for keeping the tags clean :)

Answer (score 2):

Form redirects haven't changed between Drupal 7 and 8; you still need to use `$form_state['redirect']` (incidentally `drupal_goto()` shouldn't be used within form submissions in Drupal 7, it can mess things up).

Within your form class's `submitForm()` method, you can use

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'node';
```

Or

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'node/123',
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'foo' => 'bar',
    ),
    'fragment' => 'baz',
  ),
);
```

Full info can be found in the [`FormBuilder::redirectForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AredirectForm/8) docs

Comment: Actually, it has changed, you should use redirect_route now, see https://drupal.org/node/2105661. But yes, response objects can only be returned from non-form controllers.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir, hadn't seen that one. Looking at the code for `FormBuilder::redirectForm()` now, it would also be acceptable to use `$form_state['redirect'] = new RedirectResponse('/foo');`...have I got that right or do you know will that change?

Comment: Apparently yes. But I think using the route is the preferred method.

Comment: If you use a redirect response object ensure that you generate an absolute URL. In general as berdir said using route name + parameters is the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: @Berdir Just re-visiting this...the docs for `redirectForm()` still don't have an example using a redirect_route, do you happen to know where I can find docs for that?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, you redirect a form in its `submitForm()` method by calling [`$form_state->setRedirect()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8/search/setRedirect).

This is the code used from [`UserLoginForm::submitForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Form!UserLoginForm.php/function/UserLoginForm%3A%3AsubmitForm/8), which redirects the user to user/$uid.

```
  // A destination was set, probably on an exception controller,
  if (!$this->getRequest()->request->has('destination')) {
    $form_state->setRedirect(
    'entity.user.canonical', 
    array('user' => $account->id())
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to caching, you can't modify the `form_state` from `hook_form_alter()` anymore. Instead, in order to set or alter the redirect destination of a form, you need to attach a `#submit` handler to any action buttons available on the form, e.g.:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit';
```

and set the redirect destination in there:

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('user.page');
}
```