# specific submit handler to user form

Tags: forms, 9

I have a submit handler to the user form.
It redirect the user to a specific page.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse as RedirectResponse;

/**
 * @file
 * Primary module hooks for EHESS Propositions 3 module.
 *
 * @DCG
 * This file is no longer required in Drupal 8.
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/node/2217931
 */
function ehess_propositions_3_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_form') {
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if (isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
        $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = '_ehess_propositions_3_user_profile_submit';
      }
    }
  }
}

function _ehess_propositions_3_user_profile_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $response = new RedirectResponse('/admin/content/reglement/');
  $response->send();
}
```

But the problem is that the submit handler is fired both for user update and user deletion. That block the redirection to "confirm deletion" page of user.

Is there a specific action to updating user form only and not user delete?

Comment: You are attaching the submit handler to all submit buttons, including the cancel button. BTW don't send the response, add it to $form_state. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-after-submitting-a-form

Comment: But nothing in the example distinguish beetwen update user and delete user. That was my question to which action attached the handler? Is there a "submit-update" action like ?

Answer (score 0):

$action can be `submit` and `delete`. You don't need the foreach loop if you don't want to attach the submit handler to all submit buttons.

Add the handler to the save button directly:

```
function ehess_propositions_3_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_ehess_propositions_3_user_profile_submit';
  }
}
```

For the correct way to redirect in a form see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191594/47547

Comment: thanks really. It's obvious now!